# How to take an array of objects and create arrays based on property values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and trying to take thevalues inside those objects and push them into an array based on the same property value. So for example.

```
array = [
    {name: 'John', age: 12},
    {name: 'Lily', age: 22}
]
```

I have this array of objects and now I want to iterate through it and create arrays with all name values and age values. The array also needs to be the same name as the values. So the result will be.

```
name = ['John', 'Lily']

age = [12, 22]
```

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `map` over the array like so:

```js
const array = [
 {name: 'John', age: 12},
 {name: 'Lily', age: 22}
]

const name = array.map(e => e.name);
const age = array.map(e => e.age);

console.log(name);
console.log(age);
```

## EDIT

If the array has dynamic objects, you can do this:

```js
const array = [
 {name: 'John', age: 12},
 {name: 'Lily', age: 22}
];

for (var key in array[0]) {
  window[key] = array.map(e => e[key]);
}

console.log(name);
console.log(age);
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the objects are dynamic. The number of objects and their property names are not set. How would I be able to dynamically create those arrays with the same name?

Comment: I'll add that to my answer @BiasedG

Comment: @BiasedG I've fixed it now